# How do I make a gallery in WordPress without using a plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a gallery in a WordPress post using WordPress's native media gallery and it shows me the images as gallery thumbnails in rows and columns which is exactly what I want.

But when I click on any of the thumbnail it opens the direct image link. I want that the image should be shown in my blogs environment. I would actually want it to show on the same page itself. but if not that I don't want it to open as a direct image. Is there a template file or something I could make for opening those images. I think image.php, but I have no idea how to go about it.

Help..?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're inserting a gallery into your post, you can select how to link to the images. See screenshot: http://cl.ly/2yYA

Just select 'attachment page' and you'll get an individual page with commenting for that photo. Is that what you were looking for? You can edit the template of that page using attachment.php.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked but unfortunately I don't like it. Is there a way I could implement this thing on the same page. I mean single.php with the content.

Comment: Not out of the box, unfortunately.. WordPress's default gallery functionality is weak at best. Is there any particular reason you're against using a plugin? If you're comfortable with HTML, CSS, and some JavaScript, you might check this out: http://borloz.com/automating-lightbox-galleries-using-wordpress-and-jquery/